# Display document saved in blob format

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, blob

I have to display a document saved on SQL Server in varbinary(max) format. In a previous version of the page, there was a single document displayed in the page, the method that retrieves the document and diplays it on the page was called in the Page_Load method, and it worked.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ...
  int codeSiteId = -1;
  long docId = -1;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qs["codesiteid"]))
    {
        if (!Int32.TryParse(qs["codesiteid"], out codeSiteId))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    //else return;


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qs["docid"]))
    {
        if (!Int64.TryParse(qs["docid"], out docId))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
  ShowDocumentModel(docId, codeSiteId);
  ...
}

protected void ShowDocumentModel(long documentModelId, int codesiteid)
{
    string temppath = helpsi.framework.core.Configurator.Instance.getAppSettingsValue("APP_REGISTRATION_TEMP_PATH", codesiteid);
    string filename="";
    string pdffile = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        documentLoading.Visible = true;
        string path = Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath(temppath));
        helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModelResult result = helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModel.GetDocumentModelContent(documentModelId);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.FileName))
        {
            string unescapeFileName =  HttpUtility.UrlDecode(result.FileName);
            /*unescapeFileName = unescapeFileName.Replace("&lt;", "").Replace("&gt;", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace("&#x2F;", "");
     */

            string[] blackList = {"&lt;", "&gt;", "\\+", "{", "}", "&#x2F;","\\*", ":" };
            for (int i = 0; i < blackList.Length; i++)
            {
                unescapeFileName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(unescapeFileName, blackList[i], "", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            }

            filename = Path.Combine(path, unescapeFileName.Replace(" ", "").ToLower());
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, result.Content);
            descDocumentModel.InnerText = result.DescDocumentModel;
            descDocumentModelState.Attributes.Add("i18n", result.DocumentModelState);
            descDocumentModelType.Attributes.Add("i18n", result.DocumentModelType);
            documentModelUploadDate.InnerText = PageUtil.jsonString(result.UploadDate.ToString("s"), HttpContext.Current);
            switch (result.ContentType.Split('/')[0])
            {
                case "image":
                    hfTypeFile.Value = "image";
                    hfImageFile.Value = Page.ResolveUrl(Path.Combine(temppath, Path.GetFileName(filename))); ;
                    break;
                default:
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);                        
                    if (ext.Equals(".rtf", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || ext.Equals(".doc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || ext.Equals(".docx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        if (!PdfConverter.ConvertDocToPdf(filename, Server.MapPath(temppath), codesiteid, out pdffile))
                            pdffile = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pdffile = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                    }
                    pdffile = Page.ResolveUrl(Path.Combine(temppath, Path.GetFileName(pdffile)));
                    previewFile.Attributes["src"] = pdffile;
                    previewFile.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        hfdocumentModelStateId.Value = helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModel.get<helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModel>(documentModelId).CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE_ID.ToString();
        hfdocumentModelId.Value = documentModelId.ToString();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        documentLoading.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

In the page there is an iframe to display the document preview

```
    <div class="ui-layout-center">
    <div class="wrapper" runat="server" id="content">
        <div id="viewerDocs" style="height:100%;width:100%">
            <img id="documentLoading" src="../images/loadsmall.gif" border="0" runat="server"  visible="false"/>
            <iframe id="previewFile" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="551" frameborder="0" runat="server" visible="true"></iframe> 
        </div>
        <div class="imgViewver">
            <div id="viewer" class="viewer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the page has changed, because there is not a single document anymore, but there are more documents, and the details of these documents are displayed in a grid. The document preview is not displayed in the loading of the pagem, but clicking on a grid element the document preview has to be displayed in the iframe. There is a way to perform this by jQuery, maybe transforming the ShowDocumentModel in an ajax call? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I saved the file content in a temporary file, and I return in the ajax call a JSON object containing the URL of the temporary file saved. So in the javascript file I use the URL returned to populate the src attribute of the iframe.